# Lookup Fields MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am somewhat new to MS Access and I have inherited an application with a table that uses this Lookup feature to replace a code with a value from a query to another table.

When I first used this table and exported it to Excel for analysis, I somehow got the base ID number (or whatever it would be called) rather than the translated lookup value.  Now, when I do this, I get the translated text.  The biggest problem is that while the base value is unique, the translated values are not, so I cannot use them for the work I am doing.

Can someone explain how to get the underlying ID value rather than the lookup value? Is there some setting I can use or some way to reference the field upon which the lookup is based.  When I query the ID field, I get the lookup value.  I know that the first time I did this, the spreadsheet contained the ID number not the text.

For now, I created a copy of the table and removed the lookup information from this copy, but I know I did not run into this when I did this the first time.

Thanks.

Comment: The built-in Access export will convert Lookup fields to their displayed value and not the base value.  The easiest way around this is to create a query, then modify the 'Display Control' under the 'Lookup' tab within the 'Property Sheet' menu to a value of 'Textbox' which will override the tables Lookup setting.

Comment: @Fink That is useful information, but for the full table, the answer from BankBuilder will be more efficient.  I am sure I will use your information at some point in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export to Excel, leave **Export data with formatting and layout** unchecked. This will create a spreadsheet with raw data values in Lookup fields.

[Export settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSQxk.png)

Comment: Thank you.  I had gotten in the habit of checking that box recently, but likely had not been checking it when I first extracted this data.